# automatically updates a row in php without using cron job etc, just pure php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table this is whats inside of it:

```
   id  item_id  user_name  quantity  date_expired  is_reserved
   1      2     jimmy123      5       2016-9-15         1
   2      1     kilmer        2       2016-9-17         1
```

I want to automatically update the is_reserved in jimmy123's transaction record from 1 to 0 when date_expired reaches sept. 15, 2016, how will I be able to do that automatically in PHP and MYSQL?

Comment: You can just run a php script to update the table whenever someone visits the page. Its a poor-mans solution but if your server doesn't allow cron its about your only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need a cron job, as it can be done when the visitor, or any visitor visits. In 99% of cases, this should be suitable, even if it seems a little inefficient - its how its done. Unless the is an underlying reason?  You have not given any information or code about how the username and timestamp of interest is determined, **so in my example I will hard code them assuming you will replace the values later.**

So you can get the epoche time, of that date, 1473897600. This is how you should store your dates, and then convert it to something readible if your outputting it.

Then have a script that looks something like this

```
<?php
$user = "jimmy123";
$query = "SELECT date_expired FROM users WHERE user_username = '$user'"; //assumes date_expired is now a timestamp format

$expireDate = ... //run query and get single result
if(time()>$expireDate){
    $query = "UPDATE users SET is_reserved = 0 WHERE user_name = '$user'";

   //run query

}

?>
```

Comment: so do i need to strtotime the date_expired or does 1473897600 is the date_expired? and is time() already like that? and if I use codeigniter. do I need make this at the Controller or at the Model? tnx mate! you've help me make it easier

Comment: No problem. So you haven't given me much information, but this kind of thing should be in the controller. I miss read a bit of your question, will update now. time() will get current time. And im updating the other bit. Hold on

Comment: ok updated. you need to update comments with however you run your queries (PDO? mysqli?) and presumably have a proper way of specifying the user.

Comment: im using mysqli sir, XAMPP, so whenever someone opens at that day, either it is another user(maybe kilmer not jimmy123) and the admin. it will automatically update im i right?

Comment: well, make sure $user is equal to who ever the user is, and youve made sure that the date format of date_expired is a timestamp. and i assume you know how to run those queries yourself in mysqli?

Comment: yep! i knew how sir! thank you so much! ill gave you feedback when I get home and code this thing, this is the only thing I need, coz our thesis adviser told us to not make an automatic soft deletion in the reservation area whenever the reservation is too old! thank you so much sir, God Bless you alot and Have a Merry Xmas! XD

Comment: happy to help. keep me posted.